# Websphere Name Space Bindings affect the JNDI scope resolution order

Tags: jms, websphere, jndi

Here is the situation:

I'm on websphere Network Deployment v8.0.0.3 
I've an application which use 2 queuese
One Queue is for internal application usage (Publisher and Consumer are inside the same application) the other queue is used by other modules deployed on Other application server inside the cell.

So I have configured the 1st queue at Cell Scope level and the second queue at Cluster scope level.

Everything was working until I added a Name Space Binding.
After that every jms jndi object Cluster Scoped are not present anymore inside a dumpNameSpace.sh output.

Seams like the resolution of the scopes are modified by the presence of a Name Space Binding.
Which indeed is really odd but I got the same behaviour on 2 different installations of WAS.

Thanks for anyone which knows this.

**Update**

This is the diff between the jndi dump that works and the one which not.

```
--- clsdumpOk   2012-08-07 11:49:43.000000000 +0200
+++ clsdumpKo2  2012-08-07 11:49:59.000000000 +0200
@@ -454,28 +454,12 @@
 (top)/clusters/TestCluster/jdbc/modulobase
 (top)/clusters/TestCluster/jms
 (top)/clusters/TestCluster/jms/as
-(top)/clusters/TestCluster/jms/as/BatchRequest
-(top)/clusters/TestCluster/jms/as/BatchResponse
 (top)/clusters/TestCluster/jms/as/ciccio
-(top)/clusters/TestCluster/jms/as/FSCleaner
 (top)/clusters/TestCluster/jms/as/License
 (top)/clusters/TestCluster/jms/as/Mailer
-(top)/clusters/TestCluster/jms/as/Plans
-(top)/clusters/TestCluster/jms/as/RiaResponse
-(top)/clusters/TestCluster/jms/ConnectionFactory
-(top)/clusters/TestCluster/jms/pac
-(top)/clusters/TestCluster/jms/pac/as
-(top)/clusters/TestCluster/jms/pac/as/Events
 (top)/clusters/TestCluster/jms/queue
-(top)/clusters/TestCluster/jms/queue/batch-request
-(top)/clusters/TestCluster/jms/queue/batch-response
-(top)/clusters/TestCluster/jms/QueueConnectionFactory
-(top)/clusters/TestCluster/jms/queue/events
-(top)/clusters/TestCluster/jms/queue/filesystem-cleaner
 (top)/clusters/TestCluster/jms/queue/license
 (top)/clusters/TestCluster/jms/queue/mailer
-(top)/clusters/TestCluster/jms/queue/plans
-(top)/clusters/TestCluster/jms/TopicConnectionFactory
 (top)/clusters/TestCluster/jta
 (top)/clusters/TestCluster/jta/usertransaction
 (top)/clusters/TestCluster/SecurityServer
@@ -495,8 +479,10 @@
 (top)/clusters/TestCluster/url/casCfgFile
 (top)/clusters/TestCluster/UserRegistry
 (top)/clusters/TestCluster/wb25
-(top)/clusters/TestCluster/wb25/topic
-(top)/clusters/TestCluster/wb25/topic/ria-response
+(top)/clusters/TestCluster/wb25/conf
+(top)/clusters/TestCluster/wb25/conf/locking
+(top)/clusters/TestCluster/wb25/conf/locking/lockingEnabled
+(top)/clusters/TestCluster/wb25/conf/rootFolder
 (top)/clusters/TestCluster/wm
 (top)/clusters/TestCluster/wm/ard
 (top)/clusters/TestCluster/wm/default
```

as you can see once the

+(top)/clusters/TestCluster/wb25/conf/locking/lockingEnabled

is added

all the rest is removed.
It's really weird.

Comment: You have to elaborate on this. What are the names. Spell them out on their exact values? Are the names exactly the same (except for the scope at which they are created). Adding a name space binding cannot remove existing objects from the name space.

Comment: Solved was a problem with conflicting jndi namespaces if you setup a Naming the nodes will become readonly blocking was to deploy the queue entries into the jndi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in WebSphere for Environment -> Naming -> Namespace Bindings 
is the following:
If you set some JNDI nodes with the naming:
url/someVariable
or generically
something/someVar

and than you use the same "something" for some other object like:
URL
or
JDBC
or
JMS

The Name space binding put "something" in read-only mode and when WebSphere try to configure other resources will fail.

You cannot spot this during configuration because only at the first reboot of the Application Server you will get this.

So be carefull when chose names inside jndi.